# How to store post variables value

Tags: php, post, paging

I got a Index page on which search page is included, and when I submit it, it passes values to find.php through action and method post. The code is below

```
if($_POST['searchsubmit']=="Search"){
$cat=$_POST['searchcategory'];
$area=$_POST['searcharea'];
$term=$_POST['searchbox'];
}
```

The above code is written on find.php, Now when I try to implement paging through basic paging method with where conditions to make appropiate search query

```
$where="where approved='yes'";
        if($term!=""){
            $where.=" and name like '%$term%'";
        }
        if($cat!=""){
            $where.=" and category like '%$cat%'";
        }
        if($area!=""){
            $where.=" and area like '%$area%'";
        }
        $start=0;
        $end=5;
        if($_GET['page']!="")
        {
            $start=$_GET['page']*$end;
        }
```

Where $start is my initial limit, and $end is my number of records. For the first page of paging, I pass a variable page with 0 for first page

```
<a href="find.php?page=<?php echo 0;?>">First</a>
```

and my search query now becomes

```
$que="select * from shops ".$where." ORDER BY likes DESC  limit $start,$end";
```

As soon as I click on "first", My new link become "/find.php?page=0"
and the post values which I recivied from index page search bar are lost.

Is there any way to retain those values ?The two methods which I though are sending them again through url with GET, or the other way is to store them in session. 
Is there any third method available ?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). DO NOT USE THIS CODE AS IS. To preserve your post values, store them in $_SESSION, then they'll be available for all subsequent page loads.

Comment: since you are hardcoding the value of page, you will always be on page 0 (or First according to your logic).

Comment: You need to use sessions to retain data!

Comment: @KirkBackus Not necessarily true. Sessions maintain *session* data, but there is also *page data* and *other persistent data*. In here, the problem is [likely] not using *page data*: that is, the search criteria can could (and likely should) be embedded into the "next" links so that it will be available when the subsequent request are made. An issue with session data is that it not [necessarily] tied to a specific page and thus won't work as expected on forward-back navigation.

Comment: @user2246674 He could post the data every time, but I'm not familiar with *page data* and *other persistent data*.  How does that work?

Comment: Page Data - data is persisted by means of being in the HTML Page (in HTML, URL, etc). Other Persistent Data - database, filesystem, webapi, or whatever else that neither falls under Session-stored data or Page-stored data.

Comment: @GordonM, the comic was nice , but I guess you are telling me to validate the data before using it for database queries. Validation is remaining , will be done for sure.

Comment: @MarcB, yes I know, I am just clearing my logics rite now, I will improve my code to prevent sql injection.
user2246674, you mean storing the data into some div and retriving it back through JS ?(that div would be invisible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marc is absolutely right. Do not use the code as it is.

As an alternate solution to your problem -

- Your page index.php (search form) submits to itself
- Assemble your search query as querystring in index.php if its a post
- Redirect to find.php with the assembled querystring
- Every search information will always be in the querystring.
- Use  your pagination happily.

Comment: Ok , but I lost at
"Redirect to find.php with the assembled querystring", how to do that ?
window.location="find.php" , but how to take assembled query ?

Comment: @user2454340 To redirect you can use php's `header` function. To assemble the querystring, you can simply loop through the post variables and build the querystring:
//something like
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
  $myquerystring = $myquerystring . '&' . $key . '=' . $val
}

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct.

Use:

```
// Start the session
session_start();
// Save variables into session
$_SESSION['somevalue'] = $_POST['value'];
```

Then when any page calls session_start it will have access to $_SESSION['somevalue']

Also, you are wide open for SQL injection.  Sanitize your values to ensure no one can put arbitrary sql code into the string.  if you are using mysqli it should as simple as this:

```
// After connecting to the DB
$_POST['somevalue' = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['somevalue']);
```

Then be sure to hardcode quotes around string values like you are doing.

If you want to be safer you can use prepared statement instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin rite now, And I guess sanitize means validate the data before using it in query ?

Comment: Yes.  To sanitize is to ensure that the query that gets generated does what you want it to, not what some hacker/kid wants it to.  If I had a script run that did this: "SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = $somevariable" it will work great.  But if the user makes $somevariable equal to ; DROP mytable; then the first query string would simply fail and then mytable would DROP.  It is a simple example but it can and will happen. mysqli_real_escape escapes characters likei ; " ' so no one can break out of the intended query using these special characters.

Comment: Just switched from **MySQLi** to **PDO**, would recommend it. **PDO::prepare()** *helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by eliminating the need to manually quote the parameters.*